# Why element.innerHTML = string with date info doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've come across this problem with `setInterval()`:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("demo");

function updateTime(d) {

  h1.innerHTML = "numero del mese: " + d.getDate() +
    "<br>numero della settimana: " + d.getDay() +
    "<br>anno: " + d.getFullYear() +
    "<br>mese: " + d.getMonth() +
    "<br>ore: " + d.getHours() +
    "<br>minuti: " + d.getMinutes() +
    "<br>secondi: " + d.getSeconds();
}

setInterval(updateTime.bind(null, new Date()), 1000);
```

All of this works properly, but it works only once then nothing.
Why?

Comment: Use `setInterval(updateTime, 1000, new Date());` instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — You'd have the same problem.

Comment: @Quentin yep. I see that. My first thought was with the odd (imo) null binding that was being done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date()` creates a Date object representing *the time when the object was created*

You call it once and then use it in an interval which shows that time (**which does not change**) every second.

If you want to get the *current* time, then you'll need to create a new Date object **inside** the function you call on the interval.

For example:

```
setInterval(function () { updateTime(new Date()); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your explanation. @Quentin

Answer (score 2):

The new Date object creates once and you are using the same object in every function call. So the date does not change on every call.

You need to create new Date object inside the function, so that it is created every time when the function is called and hence the time is updated.

Check the snippet below :

```js
var h1 = document.getElementById("demo");

function updateTime() {
  var d = new Date();
      
  h1.innerHTML = "numero del mese: " + d.getDate() +
    "<br>numero della settimana: " + d.getDay() +
    "<br>anno: " + d.getFullYear() +
    "<br>mese: " + d.getMonth() +
    "<br>ore: " + d.getHours() +
    "<br>minuti: " + d.getMinutes() +
    "<br>secondi: " + d.getSeconds();
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use `.bind(null, new Date())`. Hence, for every future call, it is the same date as created initially. I suggest calling `new Date()` in every interval to get the *current* time. See below.

```js
    var h1 = document.getElementById("demo");

    function updateTime() {
      let d = new Date();
      
      h1.innerHTML = "numero del mese: " + d.getDate() +
        "<br>numero della settimana: " + d.getDay() +
        "<br>anno: " + d.getFullYear() +
        "<br>mese: " + d.getMonth() +
        "<br>ore: " + d.getHours() +
        "<br>minuti: " + d.getMinutes() +
        "<br>secondi: " + d.getSeconds();
    }

    setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```